# Recenter a window after auto size changed

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a `MainDashoard` called `MainDashView` that contains a frame called `frViewer`, I click a button and it then loads a page called `pgEntryView` into `frViewer`.

The page is wider than the frame so when it loads the window width ends up off the screen.

How do I get the `MainDashView` to recenter or stay fixed to the centre of the screen after the `SizeToContent` event has fired?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I have just managed to figure out where I was going wrong.

In order to do this, I need to create the `private void CenterWindowOnScreen` as follows:

```
private void CenterWindowOnScreen(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double screenWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
            double screenHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            double windowWidth = this.Width;
            double windowHeight = this.Height;
            this.Left = (screenWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
            this.Top = (screenHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);
        }
```

My mistake came in when I didn't realise that the window was not the only object being resized, the frame was as well, thus by binding their respective `SizeChanged` properties/events to this method, I am able to always keep the Window at the center of the screen.

Comment: Hi, @TravO. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you could click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: I do apologise for the extremely late response, yes it does, thank you so much

Comment: I tried with a new window and set each control etc to that EventHandler but it does not work, the width and height of the window are larger than the screen's width and height so I honestly do know what else to do.

Comment: Hi,@TravO . Do you want the center point of a window larger than the screen size to always be in the center of the screen?

Comment: Basically, I want the window and its content to adjust its dimensions to the ratio and size of the screen it is being displayed on.